# SSAS Dax (creating measures)

Tags: ssas, dax

hopefully someone can help with this.

I am building a cube in SQL Server Data Tools 2015 and have imported my tables. I want to create a measure that basically says if a date column is 30 days older than todays date and another column is null and another column is "yes" then 1, else 0. All these columns are on the same table.

I guess I am looking for the DAX equivalent of a case statement.

Can anyone help? I have tried google but can't find anything specific to what I need.

Appreciate any help

Comment: Do you mean a calculated column rather than a measure? If not, what is your filter context for the measure?

Comment: Yes sorry I meant calculated column

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with an `IF()` function:

```
Calculated Column = IF(Table1[Date] < TODAY() - 30 && Table1[Col2] = BLANK(), 1, 0)
```

where `Table1` is the table these columns live on and `Col2` is the "another column" you mentioned.